# Testing js/esm project w/ sinon, nyc and ava - test w/ spy on console fails despite console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, ava, nyc

I have an `esm` project I'm trying to test with `ava`, `nyc` and `sinon`.  I have had some success using sinon to spy on console.log and report whether or not it is being called, but on another set of files, where I feel I'm doing the same things, I can't get it to work.  I don't know if it's sinon or ava or what is the problem.  I made a test repo [here](https://github.com/jamessouth/test-issue-repo).  When you run `npm run test` it will fail and say console.log was not called, but you can see at the top of the output a statement was logged.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is asynchronous and you only call `console.log()` after awaiting. At that point you've already torn down the spy. Use `await main()` and make the test implementation asynchronous as well.

Comment: Thank you @mark-wubben but I tried that with no luck.  I have updated the repo to make the test async and await the call to main.  The tested flow is this:  set up spy, call main with no args, no args throws an error, catch error and log message to console, test that it is true that console.log was called 1 time, remove spy.  output of `npm run test`: error message logged but test fails, async or not.

Comment: oooh finally getting somewhere - when you comment out the import statement in main, the test passes!  So I guess `esm` is where the problem lies...??